# Re-frame dispatches and subscribes not working in the repl and test files

Tags: clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, re-frame

I have a re-frame project, and my events, subs and db cljs files are populated. I use these three in my project and it works well. But I created a test file, and called subscribe and dispatch in it like so:

```
(deftest category-filter-test
  (dispatch [:add-filter "cat"])
  (is (= @(subscribe [:filters]) ["cat"]))
  )
```

And that doesn't work. I get

```
#object[Error Error: No protocol method IDeref.-deref defined for type undefined: ]
```

On the other hand, if I try to run subscribe in the shadow-cljs repl, I get the following error:

```
------ WARNING - :undeclared-ns ------------------------------------------------
 Resource: :1:2
 No such namespace: user, could not locate user.cljs, user.cljc, or JavaScript source providing "user"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------ WARNING - :undeclared-var -----------------------------------------------
 Resource: :1:2
 Use of undeclared Var user/start
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ReferenceError: user is not defined
    at eval (eval at shadow$cljs$devtools$client$browser$global_eval (http://localhost:3689/js/workspaces/cljs-runtime/shadow.cljs.devtools.client.browser.js), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Object.shadow$cljs$devtools$client$browser$global_eval [as global_eval] (http://localhost:3689/js/workspaces/cljs-runtime/shadow.cljs.devtools.client.browser.js:758:16)
    at eval (http://localhost:3689/js/workspaces/cljs-runtime/shadow.cljs.devtools.client.browser.js:767:44)
    at Object.shadow$cljs$devtools$client$env$repl_call [as repl_call] (http://localhost:3689/js/workspaces/cljs-runtime/shadow.cljs.devtools.client.env.js:167:108)
    at Object.shadow$cljs$devtools$client$browser$repl_invoke [as repl_invoke] (http://localhost:3689/js/workspaces/cljs-runtime/shadow.cljs.devtools.client.browser.js:766:46)
    at shadow$cljs$devtools$client$browser$handle_message (http://localhost:3689/js/workspaces/cljs-runtime/shadow.cljs.devtools.client.browser.js:844:37)
    at eval (http://localhost:3689/js/workspaces/cljs-runtime/shadow.cljs.devtools.client.env.js:307:151)
    at Object.shadow$cljs$devtools$client$env$process_next_BANG_ [as process_next_BANG_] (http://localhost:3689/js/workspaces/cljs-runtime/shadow.cljs.devtools.client.env.js:289:90)
    at Object.shadow$cljs$devtools$client$env$process_ws_msg [as process_ws_msg] (http://localhost:3689/js/workspaces/cljs-runtime/shadow.cljs.devtools.client.env.js:310:40)
```

How to fix these two errors?

Comment: Can you add more info about `:add-filter` and `:filters`?

Comment: Would you mind asking this as two separate questions? The second part has nothing to do with the first. It looks like you are trying to eval `(user/start)` in the REPL but the sample code you posted does not include that part. The code you posted would not end up doing this so it must be either something your editor does or something else in your code.